# Run two Laravel Echo Server (Socket.io) instances on one Server?

Tags: laravel, sockets, socket.io, laravel-echo

So I want to run two socket.io Server / Laravel Echo Server on one physical server. On this server there is a Virtual Host for Production and another one for testing purposes. Now they both need a connection to a Websocket running on the same server.

Is this possible without broadcasting Events to the wrong instance? Or should I run a second instance of the Laravel Echo Server on another port an let both Environments connect on different Socket.io servers?

Is there a common approach?